# How to call array_map() without using a closure

Tags: php, array-map

I have something like this:

```
public static function lengtOfElements($array){
    return array_map(function($item){return strlen($item);},$array);
}
```

What I want to do is to use strlen($string) directly in array_map, but when I try it it won't work.. Why is the reason?

Something like this:

```
public static function lengtOfElements($array){
    return array_map(strlen($string),$array);
}
```

Comment: because strlen is called ONCE, before array_map even starts, and its returned value is passed in to array_map as a static value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off:

```
return array_map('strlen',$array);
```